# Ruby on Rails: How do I add placeholder text to a f.text_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I add `placeholder` text to my `f.text_field` fields so that the text comes pre-written by default, and when a user click inside the fields, the text goes away - allowing the user to type in the new text?

Comment: HTML5 Supports this. In the meantime, there are [javascript solutions](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/form-input-placeholder-text/).

Comment: I suggest adding nslocum's answer instead of mine. His is correct for Rails 3.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

With rails >= 3.0, you can simply use the `placeholder` option.

```
f.text_field :attr, placeholder: "placeholder text"
```

Comment: The "placeholder" attribute is only supported by HTML5 supporting browsers, leaving out browsers like Internet Explorer.

Comment: The correct URL for jQuery fix is http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: @KDP: It seems to be the same in Rails 2, although you may need the old attribute syntax: `f.text_field :attr, :placeholder => "placeholder text"`

Comment: Is it possible to add a long text - maybe as a separate html file - as a placeholder? I'm trying to provide a template for users to write their content in.

Answer (score 32):

In Rails 4(Using HAML):

```
=f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'First Name'
```

Answer (score 17):

For those using Rails(4.2) Internationalization (I18n):

Set the placeholder attribute to true:

```
f.text_field :attr, placeholder: true
```

and in your local file (ie. en.yml):

```
en:
  helpers:
    placeholder:
      model_name:
        attr: "some placeholder text"
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. I didn't set the `placeholder: true`. After setting that like you described it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the solutions above and it looks like on rails 5.* the second agument by default is the value of the input form, what worked for me was:

```
text_field_tag :attr, "", placeholder: "placeholder text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much cleaner syntax if using `rails 4+`

```
<%= f.text_field :attr, placeholder: "placeholder text" %>
```

So `rails 4+` can now use this syntax instead of the hash syntax

Comment: How is it different from the accepted @nslocum answer?

Comment: @mlt The accepted answer got updated to similar after providing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your view template, set a default value:

```
f.text_field :password, :value => "password"
```

In your Javascript (assuming jquery here):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //add a handler to remove the text
});
```

Comment: Huffington Post's search field uses this bit of JS inside the input element:
`onfocus="if(this.value=='Search The Huffington Post')this.value=''" value="Search The Huffington Post"`
Seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

This way works to me.

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Drill hammer" %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, to implement a placeholder, you just can add the "placeholder: "text here", after your text_field name.

Hope my answer can be understood!