# In Rails, where can I find the HTML output file for, say, :first_name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to change some HTML in my views>devise>registrations>new.html.erb. Problem is, it is presented in the file like so:

```
<%= f.input :first_name %>
```

I am trying to get some overlay text, so that it says "Enter name here" in the box itself (like on the Facebook page, and many others.)

I can change this type of thing by using "View Source" on a website page with overlay, or "Inspect Element." So I know the HTML for it. But how do I do that when all my HTML is hidden behind this simple "f.input"? It's like the HTML is done with magical code and I don't know where to change it.

If I knew where the HTML and CSS for this page lived, I could make many other changes on my own, not just this one example :)

I should mention, this code came from elsewhere, I'm not yet skilled enough to do it myself, and obviously don't understand some parts.

My registrations/new.html.erb file:

```
    <br />

<!--<%= page_header do %>-->
  <!--<h1>Sign Up For Treebook</h1>-->
<!--<% end %>-->

<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">

    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), html: { class: "well form-vertical well-small" }) do |f| %>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign Up</legend>


      <%= devise_error_messages! %>
      <%= f.input :first_name %>
      <%= f.input :last_name %>
      <!--<%= f.input :profile_name %>-->
      <%= f.input :email %>
      <%= f.input :password, input_html: { autocomplete: 'off' } %>
      <!--<%= f.input :password_confirmation, input_html: { autocomplete: 'off' } %>-->

      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %><br /></br>
      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>

      </fieldset>
    <% end %>

  </div>

  <div class="span8">
    <h2>Don't Have An Account? Sign Up!</h2>
    <h3>Why Sign Up? Placeholder Text.</h3>
    <p>

      <%= image_tag "http://placekitten.com/g/200/300", class: 'pull-right'%>

      Irony consectetur pug minim, sint fap anim ugh cosby sweater lo-fi deep v. Umami mcsweeney's narwhal actually terry richardson. Aliquip banjo you probably haven't heard of them Austin kogi in, pariatur put a bird on it portland meggings tofu fanny pack veniam. Officia quis brunch cray, fashion axe craft beer ugh plaid. Meggings disrupt intelligentsia, pork belly sustainable synth proident literally magna seitan before they sold out. Four loko anim officia, consectetur godard single-origin coffee chillwave gentrify tousled ethnic vegan vice eiusmod. Cupidatat flexitarian craft beer church-key quinoa, twee skateboard direct trade sriracha typewriter tattooed chambray sartorial dolore tempor.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so far for the answers! They helped me do the specific thing I was looking for. However, I still haven't heard where that HTML file is. Right now, I have have the overlays complete, but redundant "First Name" prompts /above/ the overlay and string field. I don't know how to delete the redundant prompts I was using before (simple HTML text.) I am trying to simply delete some text, but without the HTML stuff or knowledge of that, I can't. (Ie, also how to make the text boxes bigger or smaller, etc. Where's the magical CSS HTML?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because part of it was not answered, perhaps the most important part. As the title says, I was also looking for a brief description of *how* Rails was doing it's html "magic."

It starts off with simple_form_for. Simple_form is a gem, which I did not understand at the time (I was just blindly following along with a treehouse tutorial.)

Simple_form is what makes something as terse as `<%= f.input :first_name %>`. Without simple_form, Rails 4 uses form_for. The form_for HTML is like so:

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </p>
```

The other answers were correct in helping me find the placeholder text. But without the other information I requested (give a man a fish, vs teach a man to fish) I ran into trouble immediately.

To get rid of the redundancy of the label and also the placeholder text, I might nowadays (a little wiser) simply remove `<%= f.label :first_name %><br>`.

Then the answer would be:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name'%>
```

Rails also allows more common HTML output (minus the erb <%= signs etc.) But that is not the best of the "Rails way," as I am told.

Another question that helped me out and is not dissimilar is here - [Ruby on Rails: How do I add placeholder text to a f.text_field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259234/ruby-on-rails-how-do-i-add-placeholder-text-to-a-f-text-field). I hope my info on how this seemingly cryptic ERB text helps someone out in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the placeholder attribute.

```
<%= f.input :first_name,:placeholder => "placeholder text" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

for ruby 1.8 use

```
<%= f.input :first_name,:placeholder => "placeholder text" %>
```

for ruby 1.9 use

```
<%= f.input :first_name, placeholder: "placeholder text" %>
```

Comment: First syntax will work in 1.9 as well. Second (as it is now) will produce syntax error.

Comment: @Ajey `placeholder: "placeholder text"` is adequate

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes your right it works in 1.9, but I kinda like the new syntax, reads much better and is a lot cleaner

Comment: @Ajey: that is very subjective. Hashrocket syntax ain't going anywhere, so one is free to use whichever syntax he likes.